Remove item from Reference List
I have a database „Users“ which contains the List<Doc Reference (users)> „Friendlist“. I am displaying this friendlist with Dynamic Children Querying in a Listview, each viewItem contains a remove button. I cant get the programm to remove the user-reference from the friendlist, by pressing the button. Do you have any idea on how to do this?
I am using firebase and firestore


I have tried displaying the Contents of the list using a backend query, which i couldnt get to work as it is a reference-list inside the table, i have tried removing the items using backend querying, which dosent work. I have asked Flutterflow copilot and i have watched youtubevideos, but nothing works

as it is generated from a list, you need to get your reference from the widget state. Then you can remove for that specific reference that user from the friendlist

An answer should provide the specific steps needed to solve the problem as well as supporting documentation.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
